# Issue With Report Link(Action) in Report builder 3.0

Tags: reportbuilder3.0, microsoft-reporting

I want to create drilldown report when click to particular row it will open another report.
I do this step. right click on particular field-> TextBox Properties -> Action then checked Go to report option But when I click on Browse then it didn't display any report. I have multipl[image]e reports(.rdl file) on my local.
How can I define path ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your local reports because Report Builder supports only paths to report servers.

Taken from note at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220423.aspx):

> In Report Builder, paths to items must specify items on a report server. Paths to items on a file system are not supported. You can preview a report that uses these items only if you are connected to the report server where the items are located.